# determinant of Product of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I recently studied $\det (P Q)=\det (P)\cdot \det (Q)$, now as $\det$ is scalar quantity $\implies \det (Q P)=\det (P)\cdot \det (Q)=\det (P Q)$. As matrix $PQ$ is not necessarily equal to $QP$, why is there determinant equal?

Also consider $A$ to be $2\times 3$ and $B$ to be $3\times 2$ then,

[image]

Is such  $2\times 3$ and  $3\times 2$ matrix determinant always zero?

I'm very new to this please don't use higher level of Mathematics.

Comment: determinats are only defined for square matrices

Comment: @MilanStojanovic $A$ and $B$ may not be squares but there product $BA$ is. Don't consider $A$ and  $B$ of 1st part to be equal to 2nd part of question.

Comment: The equality $\det (AB) = \det (BA)$ only holds when $A$ and $B$ are square matrices

Answer (score 1):

Determinants are not defined for $m\times n$ matrix where $m \ne n$.
$Det(A)$ is interpreted as volume of parallelepiped.

In general, you cannot define $det(AB)$ and $det(BA)$ let alone their equality, when  $A ~\&~ B$ are not square matrices. For square matrices why $det(AB)=det(BA)$ check [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product) link for proof.

Luckily, for your specific choice of $ A $ and $B$ both $AB \& BA$ matrices are defined. But this doesn't hold in general.
Take for example $A$ as $4\times 7$ and $B$ as $7 \times 3$. Your $AB$ matrix is defined as $4 \times 3$ however $BA$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

First: $A$ and $B$ do not have determinants. Only square matrices do.

Second: You correctly calculated the matrix $BA$ but that matrix is not the product of the two matrices in the last line, one with a row and one with a column of $0$s.

Third: There is some truth in what you say. The matrix $B$, considered as a linear transformation, maps a two dimensional space to a three dimensional space. That means that when you think of $BA$ as a linear transformation it can't be surjective. So it is not invertible and has determinant $0$.

The third point is not very "advanced mathematics". If you haven't seen it yet in your study of linear algebra you will soon.